# How to put Login, Register and newsletter widget on the same page?

Tags: login, user-registration

I would like to create a template file and put there a login code, register code and widget code. I can do it for a widget, but I do not know how to do such thing for login and register. Any advice how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [`wp_register()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_register/) which displays either a link to the registration or a login link.

Then you got [`wp_loginout()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_loginout/) that has either a login or logout link - depending on the login status of the user.

Another thing you could do is just adding a [`wp_login_form()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_login_form/).

You can also use the plain [`wp_login_url( $redirect )`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_login_url/) to construct a link yourself, where `$redirect` would be the query args that you want to append. Then there's also [`wp_logout_url()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_logout_url/) to do the opposite.

To check if a user is logged in, just use [`is_user_logged_in()`](http://queryposts.com/function/is_user_logged_in/).

```
<?php
/* Template Name: (#56656) LoginLogoutEtc. */

dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar_name' );

// Links to login/logout
wp_loginout();

// User is not logged in
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
{
    // Offer the login form
    wp_login_form();
}
// Multisite: User may want to register
elseif ( is_multisite() AND ! is_user_member_of_blog() )
{
    wp_register();
}

// In case the user wants to log out again
if ( is_user_logged_in() )
{
    printf(
         '<a href="%s" title="Logout">Logout</a>'
        ,wp_logout_url();
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use login and register forms as widgets also. Register more widget areas and use some plugins there. Just search for "wordpress login widget" and "wordpress registration widget".

[Registration Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/registration-form-widget/)
[Sidebar Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sidebar-login/)